# How to filter a dictionary of arrays

Tags: iphone, xcode, filter, nsdictionary, predicate

I have a dictionary of arrays which I want to filter based on an element in the arrays. My dictionary looks like this...

> ```
> "Abu Dhabi, U.A.E." =     (
>     "24.466665",
>     "54.416668",
>     "Asia/Dubai"
> );
> "Accra, Ghana" =     (
>     "5.583333",
>     "-0.100000",
>     "Africa/Accra"
> );
> "Adak, America" =     (
>     "",
>     "",
>     "America/Adak"
> );
> "Addis Ababa, Ethiopia" =     (
>     "9.050000",
>     "38.700001",
>     "Africa/Addis_Ababa"
> );
> ```

I want to filter the dictionary based on the 3rd item, for example all keys that the third item (timezone ID) is "America/Adak".

I think I can do this with keysOfEntriesPassingTest, but I am at a loss as to how to do this. I have found some sample code...

```
mySet = [myDict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
             if( [[obj port] isEqual: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 8080]]) {
                 return YES;
             else
                 return NO;
             }]
```

But I cannot figure out how to rewrite this to work in my case. I do not understand the syntax required.

Could someone please help me figure out how to implement this filter?

Thanks, John

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    mySet = [myDict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                 if ([[obj objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"America/Adak"]) {
                     return YES;
                 } else {
                     return NO;
                 } 
                }];
```

Note that, as the method name implies, the resulting set will only contain the keys, not the arrays themselves.

Comment: Thanks again. Any chance you could help me understand the syntax of the method. What is keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) trying to tell me. Obj must be the stored object, but how would you use key and what is BOOL *stop?  
ok I think I am getting it... I can use key to test the key for a match of some kind like contains or starts with. I think stop can be used to stop the filtering when the first match is found??? Not really sure how to use stop.

Comment: The method `keysOfEntriesPassingTest:` will iterate over your dictionary and call that block of code in curly braces once for every object stored in the dictionary. In the block, you can use `key` to get the `key` of the current value (e.g. `@"Adak, America"` in your case), `obj` is the value itself, and `stop` is a way to tell the method to stop the iteration at a certain point. So yes, it works as you assume. For every object that the block returns `YES`, the method stores the object's key in the set it finally returns to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ole, Thank YOU!!

The if statement in the sample code I found was not formatted correctly. I think you revised only the pertinent portion for me. For the benefit of others looking at this question, here is the final working code...

```
mySet = [citiesDictionary keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) 
         {
             if([[obj objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"America/Adak"]){
                 return YES;

             }else {
                 return NO;
             }
         }];
```